# Issue while rendering view with image as binary data in html text mvc3

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

As per requirement I am building the html in the controller and passing it to the view using the model property. Like below.

```
<div id="mainDiv" style="height:500px;overflow-y:auto">
      @Html.Raw(Model.HtmlHolder)
</div>
```

when the view is returned from the action result, while there is an image in the html text. Only image is rendered in the browser. I tried to see the viewsource by right clicking the browser window there it is just an image, page is not loading. However page loads properly when there is no image in the html text.
Here is the sample html text that is passed in Model.HtmlHolder

```
<table><tr><td><div id='secDiv519 style='height:100px;width:400px;' class='Outer_Border'><div id = 'div519'style='height:18px;width:400px;border: 1px solid;black;background-color:#6797D6;'><a style='width:20px;height:18px;margin-left:5px;' class='TrDelete' alt='delete' onclick = 'deletSection(519)' href='#'></a><a id ='cloneRow519'  style='width:20px;height:18px;margin-left:5px;' class='TrAddRow' onclick ='cloneRow(this,2)' alt='AddRow' href='#'></a></div><table id='dataTable519'style='height:100px;width:400px;' class='Outer_Border'><thead id=''><tr><th style='background-color:#0054a5; color:#f7977a'  id='' width='100px'><p>dasdsa</p></th><th style='background-color:#0054a5;' id='' width='100px'></th><th style='background-color:#0054a5;'></th></tr></thead><tr id='rowToC519'><td>  <select  class = 'select  select-width' id='dataTable519drp1' name='drp1' onchange='UpdataSectionRow(this,519)'><option value=''>--Select --</option><option selected value='1326'>ABC_Name</option><option value='1327'>ABC_ReportName</option></select></td><td><input class = 'select  select-width' style='width:120px' type='text' disabled='disabled'/><td><a id ='DeleteRow519drp1'  style='width:20px;height:18px;margin-left:5px;' class='DeleteRow' onclick ='deleteRow(this,519)' alt='DeleteRow' href='#'></a></td></td></tr></table></div></td><td><div id='secDiv520' style='width:400px;'><div id = 'div520' style='height:18px;width:400px;border: 1px solid;black;background-color:#6797D6;'><a style='width:20px;height:18px;margin-left:5px;' class='TrDelete' alt='delete' onclick = 'deletSection(520)' href='#'></a></div><table id='dataTable520' style='height:200px;width:400px;border: 1px solid black;'><thead id=''><tr><th colspan='2' style='background-color:#0054a5;color:#f7977a;' id='' width='100px'><p>rtytry</p></th></th></tr></thead><tr id='rowToC520'><td colspan='2' ><img   src='data:image/png;base64,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' name='chart' id='chart520'  alt='ChartImg'/> </td></tr></table></div></td></tr></table>
```

Please help me if anyone faced similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

When i paste your html into a clean html file and open it with IE9, there is no problem. Every browser version has it's own limit to the accepted length of an inline image data size. You could try another browser/smaller image to find out if that is your issue. Chrome 39.0.2171.95 can also display the table+image.

Comment: Html has no problem, even I tried the same after extracting the html text. Even the view is getting called but when it comes to the browser only image is rendered.